# Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error in Firefox when page reloading

Tags: angular, firefox, rxjs, rxjs6

I use `Angular 6.1.10` and `rxjs 6.3.3`. I have some service and this method, which get data, when user go to main page ("/"):

```
getCampaigns(): Observable<CampaignDto[]> {
        return this.http.get<CampaignDto[]>(this.campaignsUrl)
            .pipe(
                tap(campaigns => console.log(`fetched ${campaigns.length} campaigns`)),
                catchError(this.errorReporter.handleError('getCampaigns', []))
            );
    }
```

It's work, but when I run the app and try to refresh the page by pressing F5 quickly for example two times, I get an error in browser console:
dev mode:
[image]

prod mode:
[image]

If I press F5 slowly when the previous page refresh worked, there is no error! I broke my brain, why is this mistake happening? The error occurs only in the Firefox browser 60.4.0 esr is possible and below, on the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome no errors. Any help.

What's wrong? Maybe this is a bug in `rxjs`? It's not `CORS` problem! My frontend and backand use one url `localhost:8080`. Problem exist in dev and prod modes.

**UPDATE**:

I have `TokenInterceptor`:

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private inj: Injector) {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const auth = this.inj.get(AuthService);
        const xAuthToken = auth.xAuthToken;
        if (xAuthToken) {
            console.log(`TokenInterceptor. Getting token: ${xAuthToken}`);
            request = request.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    'x-auth-token': `${auth.xAuthToken}`
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the first screenshot you get the "campaigns: from :4200 port whereas on the second seems to be :8080. Is that correct? Does for any reason the frontend tries to send a request to server and adds a # on the endpoint?

Comment: @profanis, in first it dev mode, on second is prod mode. Error exists in both. Frontend get data by `this.campaignsUrl`. `this.campaignsUrl = '/api/campaigns'`.

Comment: @profanis, url with # it's angular view route, NOT api.

Comment: The problem indeed is odd. Do you have any HTTP interceptor?

Comment: @profanis, yes, I have interceptor `TokenInterceptor`. I updated question. But, if you remove it, the error is still there.